# How to extract hour , minute from time (11.15 AM)

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-moment

I wanted to extract hour, minute from time

For Example

Time "11.56 PM"

I want to extract Hour - 11 ,  Minute - 56 , AMPM - PM from time.

Could you please suggest how to do it in angular 6

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide what you have done so far please explain what is not working Hi Please refer this page for asking question [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.split`

```js
const time = "11.56 PM";

const [hour, parts] = time.split('.');

const [min, ampm] = parts.split(" ")

console.log(hour);
console.log(min);
console.log(ampm);
```